# WordPress Plugin- How to Insert Html&JS code in specific Page and specific Div

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I have some Html& js code relating to this dropbox button by WordPress plugin
1- I want to insert the button in a specifc page for example I have sample page and Sec Page I want to specifiy the page **because it's in all the pages**

2- When I install the plugin always appears in the beginning of the website so How to make it in a spcific `div` for example in the page I'll select

[image: Dropbox button]

I'm using `add_action()` function it works but as I mentioned appears in every page and in the beginning

```
    function hook_html()
    {
    ?>


 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/2/dropins.js" id="dropboxjs"
     data-app-key="XXXXXXX"></script>


 <div id="dropboxContainer">hellodrooppp</div>

...............
  }

  add_action('wp_head', 'hook_html');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want to insert the button on only one/few specific pages you can simply create a shortcode[[Reference]](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) and insert it on specific page/pages.

Your code will be something like:

```
function hook_html(){
     //function body
}
add_shortcode( 'dropbox_button', 'hook_html' );
```

And then just edit the specific pages and add the shortcode `[dropbox_button]` to them, you can also choose to add this in any section of the page that you want.

Comment: I think `'dropbox_button'`  is the tag? but what is it? in the reference that should be return value but in my case I don't have return value. and how to select the page that I want to insert in. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @Steve 'dropbox_button' is the shortcode. You can go to any page and edit it add the shortcode as [dropbox_button] with the square brackets and the code in function will execute on that page.

Comment: Yes It worked thanks. Can I use add_shortcode with html class ofr  `div's id` or select specifc page `div`? because it's a plugin and I can't tell everyone you've to edit the page to run the plugin, so I need something globally. –